# Angular form validation not functioning as expected

Tags: angularjs

I have a field in my form for which i want to permit only integer input. So I have setup a check as below:

```
<form name="myform">
<label><input type="number" ng-model="val1" name="val1" required integer>
<span ng-show="myform.val1.$error.integer">Integer input only</span>
```

The issue i am facing is that the error never shows up even if I enter float numbers.
Also the box does not go red. What am i missing here ?

Comment: is `integer` a custom directive? it's not a standard html attribute or angular directive.

Comment: I thought it was built into angular.. thanks Quad.. that helped

Answer (score 1):

If you are validating against a number field then should check:

```
myform.val1.$error.number
```

Answer (score 0):

`integer` is not an input directive. To use it, you will have to create one. However, you could achieve the same thing using `ng-pattern`.

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" ng-model="val1" name="val1" required />
    <span ng-show="myform.val1.$error.pattern">Integer input only</span>
    <span ng-show="myform.val1.$error.required">This field is required</span>
</form>
```

`/^\d+$/` will match integer values only. Also notice input's `type` was changed to `text`.

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranru/mGrh4/)